# new line statement for three paste0 in R

Tags: r

I want to paste to new line without quotes, I tried:

```
a<-c(5,2,8,6,11,4,7) #assign values to a vector
n=5 #assign your optimal value
ifelse(a==n, paste0(n, " is optimal.", '\n'), ifelse(a>n, paste0(a, " is high.", '\n'), paste0("Caution: ",a," is low.", '\n')))
```

I've got this output:

```
'5  is optimal. \n''Caution: 2 is low.\n''8 is high.\n''6 is high.\n''11 is high.\n''Caution: 4 is low.\n''7 is high.\n'
```

I want this output:

```
5  is optimal.
Caution: 2 is low.
8 is high.
6 is high.
11 is high.
Caution: 4 is low.
7 is high.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a printing issue.  We can wrap with `cat`

```
cat(ifelse(a==n, paste0(n, " is optimal.", '\n'), 
   ifelse(a>n, paste0(a, " is high.", '\n'), 
    paste0("Caution: ",a," is low.", '\n')))
 , '\n')
```

-output

```
# 5 is optimal.
# Caution: 2 is low.
# 8 is high.
# 6 is high.
# 11 is high.
# Caution: 4 is low.
# 7 is high.
```

---

Or another option with `glue`

```
library(dplyr)
glue::glue("{a} {case_when(a == n ~ 'is optimal'", 
     ", a > n ~ 'is high.', TRUE ~ 'is low.')}")
#5 is optimal
#2 is low.
#8 is high.
#6 is high.
#11 is high.
#4 is low.
#7 is high.
```

Comment: @user432797 `print` returns a character output and doesn't evaluate the next line returning the same output in your post without the `print` whereas `cat` doesn't have a return value.  It just prints on the console

Comment: thank you! so there is no other that I might missed?

Comment: @user432797 there is also a `glue` method,

Comment: I tried glue: `a<-c(5,2,8,6,11,4,7) #assign values to a vector
n=5 #assign your optimal value
glue(ifelse(a==n, (n, " is optimal."), ifelse(a>n, (a, " is high.")), ("Caution: ",a," is low.")))` I get this error:`Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:3:21: unexpected ','
2: n=5 #assign your optimal value
3: glue(ifelse(a==n, (n,
                       ^
Traceback:`

Comment: @user432797 Please check my updated code with `glue`

Comment: with glue I get one row: `'5 is optimal''2 is low.''8 is high.''6 is high.''11 is high.''4 is low.''7 is high.'`

Comment: @user432797 My output I updated.  It is showing multiple rows in print

Comment: both options worked flawlessly in Rstudio, but on jupyter notebook it still shows them in one row! it seems an issue with jupyter notebook, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @user432797 it could be related to evaluation of newline in jupyter.

Comment: I appreciate your support! I already upvoted every comment and accepted your answer.

Comment: @user432797 thanks  I use jupyter only for python or julia.  Have to check this